# Find all the zero divisors in the ring Z/3 × Z/6 and determine the total number of zero divisors

Tags: group-theory

Is the group of the form 
(0,0) (0,1) (0,2) (0,3) (0,4) (0,5) (1,0) (1,1) etc so there are 18 elements 
So like (0,2) . (0,3) =(0,0)   So (0,2) and (0,3) are zero divisors and others like this?

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 1):

You may observe that $\mathbb Z/6 \mathbb Z \cong \mathbb Z/2 \mathbb Z \, \times \mathbb Z/3 \mathbb Z$ not only as groups, but as rings as well (follows from Chinese remainder theorem). So your ring is a direct product of fields, therefore if multiplication by an element has kernel (= it's zero divisor) it must have at least one zero coordinate. Conversely, every element with zero coordinate is a zero divisor. So, in a ring of form $\prod_i \mathbb Z/p_i \mathbb Z$ where $\{p_i\}$ is some collection of primes, you have $\prod p_i - \prod(p_i - 1)$ zero divisors; subtract one if you want to exclude zero itself.